# I am currently trying to populate dropdown menus with a mysql server from phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql

index.html:

```
<?php
    include_once 'func.inc.php';
    connect();
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Team DriveSmart</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#008933" text="#ffffff">
    <header>
        <h1 align="center"> Team DriveSmart </h1>
    </header>
    <header>
        <h3 align="center"> Highway State </h3>
    </header>
    <section>
        <article>
            <hgroup>
            </hgroup>
            <p align="center">
            <form style="text-align:center" method="post" action="">

                <select name="dropdown1">
                    <?php query1() ?>   
                </select>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form> 
            </p>
        </article>
        <article>
        </article>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <f1 align="center"></f1>
    </footer>



    <header>
        <h3 align="center"> Highway ID </h3>
    </header>
    <section>
        <article>
            <hgroup>
            </hgroup>
            <p align="center">
            <form style="text-align:center" method="post" action="">

                <select name="dropdown2">
                    <?php query2() ?>   
                </select>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form> 
            </p>
        </article>
        <article>
        </article>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <f1 align="center"></f1>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

and then my func.inc.php looks like this:

```
<?php
    include_once 'db.inc.php';

    function connect()
    {
        mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Error connecting" . mysql_error()) ;
        mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);
    }

    function close()
    {
        mysql_close();
    }

    function query1()
    {

        $myData=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM highways_highway");
        while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData))
        {
            echo '<option value="' . $record['highway_state'] . '">' . $record['highway_state'] . '</option>' ;
        }
    }

    function query2()
    {
        $myData=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM highways_exit");
        while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData))
        {
            echo '<option value="' . $record['highway_id'] . '">' . $record['highway_id'] . '</option>' ;
        }
    }


?>
```

What I want to do is I would like to populate these dropdown menus with options from the database (e.g. in query1, I would like to populate the menus with states). The code seems to currently show a dropdown menu and a submit button, but the dropdown menu is empty and I am not sure why.

Part B: once a user selects from a dropdown menu, I would like to display the entire sql table based on the query SELECT * FROM highways_highway WHERE highway_state = dropdown1, any recommendations on doing that once part A is fixed?

Comment: @chandresh_cool He is not returning any data

Comment: I am new to php, what do I do to return data?

Comment: Nah, Chandresh was saying you need to echo your function like `echo function_name()` but you are already echoing out in functions, but you should return values instead of echoing

Comment: Are your tables populated with data? Any errors? (Besides, you should really refrain from using the deprecated mysql_* functions)

Comment: mysql is depreciated? Should I try mysqli?

Comment: Switching to mysqli does not appear to make a difference. There appears to be no errors given in the log, though I may be looking in the wrong place on cpanel

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function my_custom_function()
{
// php code here

return $myData;
}
```

or in your case

```
function query2()
    {
     $myHtmlData = '';

        $myData=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM highways_exit");
        while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData))
        {
            $myHtmlData .= '<option value="' . $record['highway_id'] . '">' . $record['highway_id'] . '</option>' ;
        }

   return $myHtmlData;
    }
```

Comment: that does not appear to work, the menus still appear blank. Is there something else I should do in the index.html to receive the return value?

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

In index.html file, echo your function like this.

```
<select name="dropdown1">
     <?php echo query1(); ?>   
</select>

<select name="dropdown2">
     <?php echo query2(); ?>   
</select>
```

and in func.inc.php file, return data like this.

```
function query1()
{
    $myselectData = '';

    $myData= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM highways_highway");
    while($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($myData))
    {
        $myselectData .= '<option value="'.$record['highway_state'].'">' . $record['highway_state'] . '</option>';
    }

  return $myselectData; 
}

function query2()
{
    $myselectData1 = '';

    $myData= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM highways_exit");
    while($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($myData))
    {
        $myselectData1 .= '<option value="'.$record['highway_id'].'">' . $record['highway_id'] . '</option>';
    }

 return $myselectData1; 
}
```

May be this help to you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Seems like I still get the same results.
[link]http://drivesmart.web.engr.illinois.edu/

Comment: @KyleGrage check my edit answer and try it. if any error then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the problem was I named the file index.html instead of index.php, sorry about that guys and thanks for the help